# Can an ILMerge'ed dll be referenced from outside?

Tags: c#, dll, dependencies, exe, ilmerge

Lets say, we have solution with 2 projects: `A` & `B`. `A` - is an **exe**cutable-assembly, `B` - is a **library**-assembly. Both depends on some 3rd-party dll, say, `3rdParty.dll`.

So we have dependencies:

`B` refers `3rdParty.dll`.

`A` refers `B` & `3rdParty.dll`.

We want to ILMerge `B` with its dependencies (in this case the only - `3rdParty.dll`) into single dll - say, `MergedB.dll`.

*Question:* `A.exe` uses its dependency `B` from `MergedB.dll`. But can `A.exe` also use `3rdParty.dll` from within `MergedB.dll`? If it can, how can we achieve it? My attempts for now fails with something like:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '3rdParty, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789abcdef' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I guess, it's impossible to refer some ILMerge'ed assembly (except the primary one - in this case `B`). But I can't find confirmation of this guess.

Comment: There are no source dlls anymore. Only the merged one. But it contains all types from the source dlls. So referencing the merged.dll should be sufficient (in most cases).

Comment: @Ralf, thanks. But let me ask clarifying question, please: Now my project `A` csproj references contains `ProjectReference` to `B` & `Reference` to `3rdParty`. Should I refer to `MergedB` (build-and-then-ILMerge-artifact) instead? Or can I declare reference to `3rdParty` in more elegant way?

Comment: I don't know if elegant. Neither of this can be elegant when merging is involved. The more normal case would be to merge all the own stuff including the executable. So no distinction between executable and library and leave third party stuff as it and don't merge it. You don't have those under control they might have used code or are going to use code in a future version you want to use that isn't compatible with merging.

Comment: Your envisioned way involves a two step build. First merge and build the library and then reference that from your executable and build that. Possible but in no way elegant.